# PHP MySQL - Charset not taken into consideration

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a php file that inserts data to a mysql db using pdo. When I try to insert the word `référencé` in a field in one of my table, it is showing in mysql like `rÃ©fÃ©rencÃ©`
I do not get it as I specified a little everywhere the charset as utf-8. See below.

1. my table is set to innodb utf-8
2. my field is set to utf8_general_ci
3. at the top of my php script i put
   a. `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
   b. `mysql_set_charset('utf8');`
   c. `mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'");`

Here below my pdo connexion function:

```
function connexion($host, $user, $pass, $db){
    $db_host = $host;  
    $db_user = $user;  
    $db_password = $pass;  
    $db_database = $db;               
    return $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_database", $db_user, $db_password);
}
```

Hope someone can help me understand. Thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc

Comment: That does not look like PDO. Are you using PDO or mysql_*?

Comment: Try executing "SET NAMES UTF8" query in MySQL as well. Also how do you display the data? It might be insterted properly but the encoding might brake where you display it.

Comment: Hello decese. I switched from mysql_ to pdo...

Comment: And are you setting the connection encoding for that PDO connection somewhere as well?

Comment: @deceze I hust edited my post and added my pdo connecxion function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently you're not setting the connection encoding for your PDO connection. Do it like so:

```
return new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_database",
               $db_user,
               $db_password,
               array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php.